# How many unique points are required to solve a generalized bell-shaped curve?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions

I have a function $g(n)$ which has the following points:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|}
n & g(n) \\ \hline
\frac{1}{\infty} \text{ or } 0 & 4 \\ \hline
\frac{1}{2} & \pi \\ \hline
1 & 2\sqrt{2} \\ \hline
2 & \pi \\ \hline
\infty & 4
\end{array}
$$

I know that $g(n) = g(\frac{1}{n})$, $g(1)=2\sqrt2$, and $g(n) = $ undefined (or $\infty$) when $n < 0$. I'm trying to figure out how to find the equation of the curve which characterizes these values.

From my understanding the formula for a generalized bell-shaped (-ish) curve is

$$
f(x)=a \cdot e^{-\left(\frac{|(x-b)|^p}{2c^2}\right)}+d
$$
Where:

- $a$ is the height parameter (the absolute value of the $y$-value of the asymptote minus the $y$-value of the turning point is equal to $a$),
- $c$ is a spread parameter,
- $b$ is the horizontal shift parameter, i.e. the $x$-value of the turning point (being the maximum point where $a>0$ and the minimum point where $a<0$),
- $d$ is the vertical shift parameter, i.e. the horizontal asymptote is equal to $d$ (unless $p\le0$, then the horizontal asymptote is $1+d$), and
- $p$ is the curve parameter (for lack of a better term), i.e. it reflects the shape of $f'(x)$ or how rapidly $f(x)$ changes - I'm not sure how to best describe the characteristics of $p$.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to solve for a specific generalized bell-shaped curve (as per the above $f(x)$), given any set of points?
2. What is the smallest number of unique points required to be able to solve for the formula of $f(x)$?
3. Is there a required distance between the points in order to be able to solve for $f(x)$? Do I need to know the asymptote and turning point?
4. Because I know the asymptote and the turning point, does that change anything?

Comment: $+1,$ good question. Maybe try writing the formula for $f(x)$ as $
f(x)-d=a \cdot e^{-\left(\frac{|(x-b)|^p}{2c^2}\right)}
$ and then take logarithms of both sides? Then substitute the points in and find the value of the constants?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I can't substitute the points at $\infty$ and $\frac{1}{\infty}$ into that equation to find the constants though, correct? My understanding is that it's not permissible to substitute the limit to infinity into the equation, or at least that it won't tell you any exact value of anything.

Comment: Sometimes substituting the limit to infinity into an equation *does* tell you something: it's like an initial condition. You get this in for example quantum mechanics in an infinite square well: the boundary conditions are at minus infinity and +infinity (if I recall correctly).